# Problem with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-ndk

I'm beginner with android and I have problems.
I configured my first emulator and my first project, but I got some errors.

````
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (26 s 860 ms)

Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
            C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
            Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
            spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
            while using Android Studio.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.```
````

Comment: Post your build.gradle files

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project and rebuild it. also restart the AVD.

Comment: Hi. Thank for your answer, but I got it. I don't remember exactly what I did, but it worked.